# Group with minimal order which maps to a given subgroup under homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $\psi:{H}\mapsto{H}'$ be a surjective homomorphism.

Can there exist a proper subgroup ${M}$ of ${H}$ such that $\psi({M})={H}'$? Can there exist more than one such subgroup? Should they be disjoint (except for the identity element)? I'm looking for specific examples in the case of existence and if not, proof of non-existence. If so, how many such subgroups exist (like, can we deduce that number in terms of order of kernel or something like that)?

Comment: Why did you make things so complicated? Why not just say you have a surjective homomorphism from $H$ to $H'$, and forget about $G$ and $G'$? (That's the situation if I understand correctly.) Also, why the funny fonts? Why not make it easy to read and answer, rather than the opposite?

A subgroup $M$ of $H$ will have this property if and only if $KM=H$, where $K$ is the kernel. Sometimes, there will be no such $M$ (if and only if $K$ is contained in the Frattini subgroup of $H$), other times, there can be many, with all kinds of intersection. This situation is too general to say much about.

Comment: Here's an example to show that things are messy. Take $H=S_n$, $H'=C_2$ and $\psi$ the sign morphism, so $K=A_n$. Then a subgroup $M$ of $H$ will project surjectively if and only if it contains an odd permutation. There are many such subgroups, with all kinds of intersections.

Comment: I've made some changes to the question as per your suggestions.

Comment: @verret, in the example you gave, can we choose an M which doesn't have the entirety of K? Like, an odd permutation with order 2 and the identity transformation together form a subgroup right?

Comment: Yes, any subgroup containing an odd permutation will do.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary homomorphism you will not be able to find such a subgroup. You do at least need that the restriction of $\psi$ to $\mathbb{H}$ is not injective, such that you can kill elements without changing the image.

Comment: My bad. I wanted to ask "can there exist" instead of "does there exist". I'll edit the question.